# Sets with zeta functions that are not the primes

Tags: cv.complex-variables, zeta-functions

Does there exist a set $S \subset \mathbb N$ such that the Dirchlet density of $S$ is well-defined and positive, the Dirchlet density of $S \cap \operatorname{PRIMES}$ is well-defined and zero, and:

$ \prod_{n \in S} \frac{1}{1-n^{-s}}$

has a meromorphic continuation to the whole complex plane? Can we construct it?

Motivation: How special is the set of primes, among sets of natural numbers of approximately the same size, for having a meromorphic continuation? I would guess that analytic continuation should be a very rare occurrence, but I don't have an intuition for how rare, or how hard it is to find an example if one exists.

Extra credit for a functional equation.

Comment: I wonder what happens if $S$ is the set of numbers of the form $p+1$, $p$ being prime. 

Answer (score 6):

You're asking about how special the prime numbers are as a subset of the integers. One can equally well ask how special the sequence $a_k = 1$ is when viewed as the sequence of coefficients of a Dirichlet series. I don't have anything to offer on your original question, but have read a few things about the latter question that may be of some interest:

1. According to Section 8 of David
   Farmer's article titled [Basic
   Analytic Number Theory](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408154), if $f(s)
       = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{k^s}$ where
   the $a_k$ are integers, then a
   sufficient condition for $f(s)$ to
   admit a meromorphic continuation *to $\Re{(s)} = 0$* is that:

   (1) $a_k$ is of subpolynomial growth

   (2) $a_k$ is multiplicative

   (3) If $p$ is prime then $a_{p^m}$ is
   independent of $m$

   and may or may not have a natural boundary there.
2. According to section 9.5 of Titchmarsh's [The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198533691), if $a_k = 0$ when $k$ is composite and $a_{k} = 1$ when $k$ is prime then $f(s)$ (provably) has a natural boundary at $\Re{(s)} = 0$
3. I've also heard of results of the type "a Dirichlet series with $a_k$ chosen at random uniformly from $[-1, 1]$ has natural boundary $\Re{(s)} = 0$ with probability $1$," but don't know  a precise statement or a reference.

Comment: What do you mean by a "natural boundary"? Unfortunately I think the second condition is never satisfied by a sequence satisfying my conditions, because it implies that $S$ consists only of prime powers, but the set of prime powers that aren't primes has Dirchlet density zero.

Comment: Natural Boundary: analytic continuation to that line, but no further owing to an accumulation of zeros or poles on the line forcing the function to be identically 0 or infinity under the assumption of an analytic continuation beyond the line - a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, you're right that the second condition that I list and yours are mutually exclusive - again, the things that I mention are about the cognate question that I mention, not your original one.